# How to approach mixed Cauchy-Dirichlet wave equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the following problem;

$u_{tt} = u_{xx}+\sinh x $

$u(0,t) = u(1,0) = 0$

$u(x,0) = u_t(x,0) = 0$

I have no clue where to start here. I tried solving it with separation of variables as a wave equation but this was not successful.

Comment: Are you sure the boundary condition $u(1,0) = 0$ is correct? Maybe it should be $u(1,t)=0$?

Comment: The boundary condition is stated in the problem as I stated it in my question.

Comment: it is probably a typo. The right boundary condition should be the one mentioned by Frits Veerman.

Comment: Rewrite the equation as $(u+\sinh x+A+Bx)_{tt} = (u+\sinh x+A+Bx)_{xx}$, where $A$ and $B$ are chosen so that $v=u+\sinh x+A+Bx$ satisfies $v(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$. Then $u(x,0)=A$ and $u_{t}(x,0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula), you see that the initial condition $u(x,0) = u_t(x,0) = 0$ yields the trivial solution to the homogeneous problem. On that same page, using the results for the homogeneous problem, a [closed form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Inhomogeneous_wave_equation_in_one_dimension) is given for the inhomogeneous problem. As it happens, this closed form solution obeys the mixed boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(1,0) = 0$.